# Death question in Roblox

Tags: roblox

Say, if there were only three players in the server "epic minigames", but then they played the marble-bomb game, so does everyone explode because the exploding numbers are greater than 3, or does the last person who survives win?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are only three players in *Epic Minigames* and they play Bomb Ball (the marble-bomb game), the last person surviving would win. In other minigames, the same thing happens, either no one survives or, if there are too little people, the last person wins.

Answer (score 0):

It's the last person who wins, because experienced scriptures usually deal with these problems, so I don't think you have to worry about that.

Comment: What are 'experienced scriptures'?